# SQL Exception: Unexpected token for UcanaccessConnection.prepareStatement

Tags: java, sql, ucanaccess

In this code, I am checking a database for records with a certain ID. If the ID is not found, the database will be updated with a new record:

```
public void save() throws SQLException {
    String checkSQL = "Select count(*) as count from people where id=?";
    PreparedStatement checkStatement = con.prepareStatement(checkSQL);

    String insertSQL = "insert into people (ID, NAME, NI_NUMBER, NI_CAT, MOBILE_NUM, EMAIL, ADDRESS, AREA, POSTCODE) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) )";
    PreparedStatement insertStatement = con.prepareStatement(insertSQL);

    for (Employee person : people) {
        int id = person.getId();
        String name = person.getName();
        String NINumber = person.getnINumber();
        NICatagory cat = person.getnICatagory();
        String mobileNumber = person.getMobileNum();
        String email = person.getEmail();
        String address = person.getAddress();
        String area = person.getArea();
        String postcode = person.getPostCode();

        checkStatement.setInt(1, id);

        ResultSet checkResult = checkStatement.executeQuery();
        checkResult.next();

        int count = checkResult.getInt(1);

        if (count == 0) {
            System.out.println("Inserting person with id " + id);

            int col = 1;
            insertStatement.setInt(col++, id);
            insertStatement.setString(col++, name);
            insertStatement.setString(col++, NINumber);
            insertStatement.setString(col++, cat.name());
            insertStatement.setString(col++, mobileNumber);
            insertStatement.setString(col++, email);
            insertStatement.setString(col++, address);
            insertStatement.setString(col++, area);
            insertStatement.setString(col++, postcode);

            insertStatement.executeUpdate();

        } else {
            System.out.println("Updating person with id " + id);
        }

    }
    insertStatement.close();
    checkStatement.close();
}
```

Upon compiling I receive [THIS](https://pastebin.com/yGcdq60z) error

Any ideas how to get around this? Someone suggested i use brackets around the column names however this did not solve my issue. I have also seen a suggestion to use *Statement* rather than *PreparedStatement* however im not sure how to implement this as it does not allow *checkStatement.setInt(1, id);*

Comment: Possibly the accepted answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222261/hsqldb-unexpected-token

Comment: Which statement fails? The insert or the select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an additional `)` at the end of the insert statement:

```
String insertSQL = "....... ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) )"; 
                                                    ^
                                                    | here
```

That should be:

```
String insertSQL = "....... ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: Sometimes I wonder what is the point in trying..... hahaha. Cheers for catching that out.